# Nested queries in npm mysql node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

Calling a nested query. I need to call 2 queries in one api call in node js. I am using npm mysql library. 1st query runs but the 2nd don't. How can i run both queries one by one?

```
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  conn.query(
    "Delete FROM assignedcourses WHERE CourseID = ?",
    req.params.id,
    async (err, results) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      conn.query(
        "Delete FROM courses WHERE CourseID = ?",
        req.params.id,
        async (err, results) => {
          res.send(results);
        }
      );
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: What happens ? What are the result of your code execution ? Errors ?!

Answer (score 0):

You can run the commands "parallel" with promises.
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```js
router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {  
  Promise.all([
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      
      // execute query
      conn.query("Delete FROM assignedcourses WHERE CourseID = ?", req.params.id, (err, result) => {
        
          if(err){
            return reject(err);
          }
        
        // query done
        resolve(result);
        
      });
      
      
    }),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      
      // execute query
      conn.query("Delete FROM courses WHERE CourseID = ?",  req.params.id, (err, results) => {
                 
          if(err){
            return reject(err);
          }
        
        // query done
        resolve(result);
        
      });
      
    }),
  ]).then((results) => {
    
    // do something with both results
    res.send(results);
    
  }).catch((err) => {
    
    // handle query errors here
    res.status(500).end(err.message);
    
  });  
});
```

There is no need for the `async` keyword.